# STM32F4DIS-BB + RTOS httpserver_socket example

Tags: freertos, stm32f4discovery, lwip

I try example from `ST` for baseboard `STM32F4DIS_BB` + `STM32F4-discovery`.
I want to use `RTOS` example httpserver_socket. Before I use standalone (`NO RTOS`) httpserver example without problems. But in `RTOS` example the server was freeze on every web connection. It means that task are OK for `LED` toggle,`DHCP` is OK etc. Ping from `CMD` is OK. But when I make connection from web client the board was freezed and go to `HardFault_Handler()`.
Any opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [debugging the hard fault](http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html) to see which instruction caused it?  Once you know that you will be able to place a break point in the code to see how you got there.

As an aside, we have [FreeRTOS+TCP](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/index.html) running on an STM32F4 now, but on the larger eval board, rather than the Discovery board.

Comment: Hi, I try it but the code is in asm inline and it make error messages that #1113: Inline assembler not permitted when generating Thumb code.

Comment: When  #pragma asm  /  #pragma thumb  are used : error  #1114-D: this feature not supported on target architecture/processor

Comment: OK I use debuging output wizh this flag:In Hard Fault Handler  SCB->HFSR = 0x40000000  Forced Hard Fault  SCB->CFSR = 0x00000001

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Richard. I found by debug and  CFSR  register that problem is in mem management :

> "processor attempted an instruction fetch from a location that does
>   not permit execution. This fault occurs on any access to an XN region,
>   even when the MPU is disabled or not present"

But I dont understand how can ST make example for the same hardware what I have with this error? Now I try to find a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that problem is in FPU option in project setting. Original project has set use FPU .When I set not used then project are OK. Problem in use of FPU and freeRTOS .